# Minimum perfect matching with uneven vertices?

Tags: graphs, matching

Given this graph, what is the minimum perfect matching? What do you do, when there is an uneven number of vertices?
[image]

Comment: What do you think and what did you try?

Comment: What do you mean by "minimum perfect matching"?

Comment: What do the labels on the edges mean?

Answer (score 1):

A perfect matching is one that includes every vertex so only graphs with an even number of vertices can have a perfect matching. If the number of vertices is odd, there is simply no perfect matching.

Comment: Sometimes one considers "almost perfect matchings" in which all vertices but one are matched.